# Can't filter out OUs contains computer objects

Tags: c#, filter, active-directory

I have an application written in c# which retrieves the top level of objects like (OUs, Containers, etc.) But the filter I've applied also brings an OU & a Container which contains computer objects.
I want only the top level objects like OUs, Containers, Groups which only contains users objects and skip the OUs which contains computer object type.

I've below filter query but it is not filtering out the OU & Container which contains computer objects.

```
(|(objectclass=domain)(objectclass=domainDNS)(objectclass=organization)(objectclass=organizationalunit)(objectclass=inetOrgPerson)(objectclass=group)(objectclass=groupOfNames)(&(objectclass=container)(!cn=computers)))
```

I want to get only the OUs, Containers & Groups which has user objects only and skip all OUs Containers which have computer objects.

Answer (score 0):

LDAP queries are limited to looking at the attributes of an object itself. So sometimes, if I'm not sure what I can query, I'll use AD Users and Computers, open the properties of an object (like an OU in this case) and look at the Attribute Editor tab to see what attributes and values are there that I can search for.

If you do that for an OU, you will see that there aren't any attributes that tell you the type of objects that are in the OU.

So the short answer to your question is that you cannot search for OU's, containers and groups that only contain computer objects.

You will have to first find *all* OUs, containers and groups with a query like:

```
(|(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(objectClass=container)(objectClass=group))
```

and then do a separate search to see if they contain computer objects.

If you're using [`DirectorySearcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher), you can set the [`SearchRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.searchroot) to an OU to only search only one OU. Then you would search for `(objectClass=computer)` to find computer objects inside. You might also want to set [`SearchScope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.searchscope) to `OneLevel` to only find objects that are direct descendants of that OU.

For groups, you can search the domain for computer members of that group using:

```
(&(memberOf=groupDN)(objectClass=computer))
```

where `groupDN` is the `distinguishedName` of the group.

Comment: One optimization can be done to minimize search operations: what if make a search to find all computers and retrieve parents from their distinguished names. Then filter ous with this list

Comment: Yes, that would work! That's a good idea. You can also pull the `memberOf` attribute in that search to find groups that have computers in them.